# C# VSTO Outlook: Disable auto complete for input controls

Tags: c#, autocomplete, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook AddIn (C#/VSTO) for our Company and some users started to complain about the autocomplete feature.

In my case it is a combobox where you can type in the name you want to search for.
The TextChanged Event will now add only the revelant items to give a clear result view in the dropdown selection.

But now if I want to search for Test Company and then want to search in the next step only for Test, Outlook starts to complete the input automatically to Test Company.

I know that pressing backspace will remove the suggestion, but it would be great if this could be completely disabled.

I googled it, but it seems that nearly nobody has required that before.

[Here you can see the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHAtD.png)

Is it possible to disable the auto complete feature?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the RibbonComboBox method does not allow you to override the auto-complete feature.  All that you can do with it is detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribboncombobox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for configuring that feature. Feel free to leave your feedback [here](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows).

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)